# Почему не работает алгоритм RSA шифрования?

Tags: c++, rsa

Всем доброго времени суток

Я реализовал алгоритм шифрования RSA, но он не работает при заданных p, q, n, e, d.

Чтобы не писать много кода, я взял два взаимно простые p и q, посчитал n, взял e такое, что НОД(e, (p-1)*(q-1)) = 1, с помощью онлайн калькулятора нашел открытий ключ d, который равен обратному числу по модулю к e.

Код:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static int p = 7;
static int q = 29;
static int n = p * q;
static int e = 17;
static int d = 89;

bool encrypt(std::string& strToEncrypt)
{
    if (strToEncrypt.size() < 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Incorrect string to be encrypted.\n";
        return false;
    }
    std::string buffStrToEncrypt = strToEncrypt;
    strToEncrypt.clear();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < buffStrToEncrypt.size(); i++)
    {
        uint64_t k = pow(buffStrToEncrypt[i], e);
        int var = k % n;
        std::cout << var << " -- " << (char)var << std::endl;
        strToEncrypt += var;
    }
    return true;
}

bool decrypt(std::string& strToDecrypt)
{
    if (strToDecrypt.size() < 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Incorrect string to be encrypted.\n";
        return false;
    }
    std::string buffStrToDecrypt = strToDecrypt;
    strToDecrypt.clear();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < strToDecrypt.size(); i++)
    {
        uint64_t k = pow(buffStrToDecrypt[i], d);
        int var = k % n;
        std::cout << var << " -- " << (char)var << std::endl;
        strToDecrypt += var;
    }
    return true;
}

void main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello";
    std::cout << "Inputed: " << str << std::endl;
    encrypt(str);
    std::cout << "Encrypted: " << str << std::endl;
    decrypt(str);
    std::cout << "Decrypted: " << str << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Но алгоритм не работает.

Вот что выводится на экран:

`Inputed: Hello
99 -- c
99 -- c
99 -- c
99 -- c
99 -- c
Encrypted: ccccc
Decrypted:`

Кто-то может подсказать почему он не работает ?

Answer (score 2):

Я даже не пытаюсь разбираться во всем коде... Этого достаточно:

```
uint64_t k = pow(buffStrToEncrypt[i], e);
```

Допустим, символ всего лишь латинская `A` - т.е. 65. `e` у вас равно 17. Итого - `65^17`, что составляет примерно `6.6e30`. Вы же пытаетесь воткнуть его в 64-битное целое... С `d=89` все еще гораздо хуже...

Не говорю уж о том, что шифровать текст посимвольно - это по сути использовать подстановочный шифр, с которым лихо справлялись еще тогда, когда самым крутым компьютером были счеты :)

Comment: Я изменил тип данных на double, теперь все шуфруеться, но не расшифровывается

Comment: А нельзя. Потому что операции сугубо целочисленные. Теперь вы получаете не переполнение, а округление :) - с тем же нулевым успехом...

Comment: А что тогда делать ?

Comment: Использовать другие методы. Например, длинную арифметику. Или, например, сообразить, что для `a^n % m` не обязательно считать `a^n` - можно взять 1, и `n` раз выполнить умножение на `a` с последующим взятием остатка от деления на `m`...